# Linked Lists && pass by reference

Tags: c, pass-by-reference, singly-linked-list

Hi I am a beginner in C can you explain to me why I don't need call by reference when I insert a new node after the given prev_node ( I made changes to prev node I change the prev->next so I need call by reference)
but I need double-pointer when I insert a new node at the beginning or at the end of the list (Why only when I have the head as an argument I need call by reference )

```
/* Given a reference (pointer to pointer) to the head of a list and
           an int, inserts a new node on the front of the list. */
        void push(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data)
        {
            /* 1. allocate node */
            struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
         
            /* 2. put in the data  */
            new_node->data  = new_data;
         
            /* 3. Make next of new node as head */
            new_node->next = (*head_ref);
         
            /* 4. move the head to point to the new node */
            (*head_ref)    = new_node;
        } 
 
        /* Given a reference (pointer to pointer) to the head
           of a list and an int, appends a new node at the end  */
        void append(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data)
        {
            /* 1. allocate node */
            struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
         
            struct Node *last = *head_ref;  /* used in step 5*/
         
            /* 2. put in the data  */
            new_node->data  = new_data;
         
            /* 3. This new node is going to be the last node, so make next of
                  it as NULL*/
            new_node->next = NULL;
         
            /* 4. If the Linked List is empty, then make the new node as head */
            if (*head_ref == NULL)
            {
               *head_ref = new_node;
               return;
            }


/* Given a node prev_node, insert a new node after the given
           prev_node */
        void insertAfter(struct Node* prev_node, int new_data)
        {
            /*1. check if the given prev_node is NULL */
            if (prev_node == NULL)
            {
              printf("the given previous node cannot be NULL");
              return;
            }
         
            /* 2. allocate new node */
            struct Node* new_node =(struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
         
            /* 3. put in the data  */
            new_node->data  = new_data;
         
            /* 4. Make next of new node as next of prev_node */
            new_node->next = prev_node->next;
         
            /* 5. move the next of prev_node as new_node */
            prev_node->next = new_node;
        }
```

Comment: "Call by reference" is a high-level language concept that doesn't apply to C. All function arguments are passed by value--it's just that some of those values are memory addresses that you can de-reference to access what they point to.

Answer (score 0):

`push()` and `append()` need to modify the `Node*` pointer itself that is being passed in. They are assigning the memory address of a new `Node` object to the passed `Node*`. Thus, you need to pass in that `Node*` by pointer so that the modification can be reflected back to the caller.  For example:

```c
struct Node* head = NULL;
push(&head, 12345);
// head points at the new Node...
```

If the caller's `Node*` were passed by value instead, that `Node*` would not be updated, eg:

```c
struct Node* head = NULL;
push(head, 12345);
// head is still NULL, and the new Node is leaked!
```

`insertAfter()` does not need to modify the `Node*` pointer itself that is being passed in. It modifies only the *contents* of the `Node` object that is being pointed at (specifically, the `Node`'s `next` field).  The `Node*` pointer itself is not being changed to point at a different `Node` object, it will keep pointing at the same `Node` it started with, and thus it can be passed in by value.

Comment: Can you explain me a little more  because maybe I have something misunderstood in Insert after I modify one of the members of the prev_node (Last line prev_node->next how this  change will be reflected bact to the caller if I do not pass by reference?

Comment: You are modifying a member of a `Node` object, you are not modifying the `Node*` pointer that is pointing at that `Node` object. There is a difference. So, it is safe to pass that `Node*` pointer by value into `insertAfter()`, because the `Node*` itself is not being changed to point at a different `Node` object, like with `push()` and `append()`.  The `Node`'s `next` field is being modified instead. Upon exit, the passed `Node*` will keep pointing at the same `Node` it started with upon entry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass by reference an object that you are going to change it itself in a function. Otherwise the function will deal with a copy of the passed object.

In all your examples of functions you are passing an object that can be changed by reference.

In the functions push and append you are passing by reference the pointer to the head node that might be changed in the functions.

In the function `insertAfter`  you are passing by reference the object (data member) next of the current node

```
void insertAfter(struct Node* prev_node, int new_data)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So dereferencing the pointer you can change the object next that is a data member of the pointed node

```
prev_node->next = new_node;
```